# What is a good way to find information on previous ban lists?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Many people say it's fun to go back and play previous formats of Yu-Gi-Oh, like the popular "Goat Format" from the mid 2000s. I have been having a hard time finding a resource to easily view every banlist since the beginning of the game (for the TCG). Is there a good website to look at that might have all this information in one place? The TCG NA website does not have easy ways to access previous banlists, which I was really surprised by.

Bonus points if there's also a way to find out what the available cardpool was for these periods, though you probably could work that out yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old post but still comes up at the top of google so thought id share this resource for anybody like me who comes across this post. This is easily the best option currently:

[www.yugiohbanlistarchives.com](http://www.yugiohbanlistarchives.com)

Users can query by date and it displays the banlist as you would see it on the official konami site and its completely up to date.

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks for sharing this, I'll definitely be using this from now on assuming it continues to be up to date.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a good website to look at that might have all this information in one place?

Seems that the good ol' Wiki has a complete  collection of [Historical Banlists](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Forbidden_%26_Limited_Lists).

It seems *very* exhaustive and complete.

I also found a [Historic Limited/Forbidden Chart](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Historic_Forbidden/Limited_Chart) which displays the information regarding forbidden and limited cards in a graphical way (green, yellow, red color code). Perhaps that is a better way to see the evolution of bans of cards.

Comment: I've come across the chart before, and it's nice, except it hasn't been updated for banlists within a few years. The Wiki seems fine other than the fact that the lists aren't ordered. I would love to see anything more user-friendly than this though.

Comment: You can always give some love to the wiki and edit it (?) lol ... will see if I find any other useful reference

Comment: It's not a website, so probably isn't worth making an answer out of, but it can also be noted that most versions/derivatives of YGOPro are able to use banlists from quite a while back; I can't check the exact range at the moment, but from what I recall it goes back quite a ways. The only disadvantage is that there's no real way (as far as I'm aware) to filter out only the cards from the F/L list.

Comment: @squid true. On ygo pro you can ... "browse"? on those past formats and select the one you want to apply for your current deck/game

Comment: How do you do that? My ygopro only seems to have the current banlist, never any history of past lists. Is there some setting I need?

Comment: IIRC, on the Deck Building on the upper menu there is a part wher eyou selec the banlist or legality. There you can chose a specific banlist, or no banlist at all. IIRC, it has quite some lists, but I am not sure if it has all

Answer (score 2):

Other option could be:

- [Forbidden & Limited Card List in yugioh-card.com/uk](https://www.yugioh-card.com/uk/gameplay/detail.php?id=1155)

There, you can check the current and previous banlists.

Answer (score 1):

After a few months, I've found a good resource as of the January 20th TCG banlist. [In this reddit post,](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/dfrq78/tcg_and_ocg_banlist_timeline_october_2019_update/) user u/mtsoren882 created a google sheets spreadsheet documenting all TCG banlist changes. It seems fairly exhaustive, and has been updated once since it was created in October of 2019. I'm unsure how long it will be supported into the future, but as of right now this seems to be the most complete resource.

I like this more than the lists on the wiki, since all changes are easy to follow, and are put in order. Hope this helps people in the future!

Answer (score -2):

Thought I would also add in that there is this website I made earlier this year, and it auto-updates the ban lists displaying them similarly to the main Yugioh website. It also generates .conf files if you want to download them:
http://ygo.anihelp.co.uk

Comment: Disclosing your affiliation is necessary here, thank you.  However, some people strongly disagree with self-promotion on this site so you may face some downvoting. [help/behavior]

Comment: +1 This seems like a genuinely useful case of self-promotion. "How do I do that thing?" "Here, I made this thing to help you do that thing."